# Does the OnActionExecuted method of an attribute always execute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes

I've searched high and low and I can't seem to find a straight answer.

If I have a custom attribute/filter, will the `OnActionExecuted` method always be called? Even if there is an exception thrown?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At least with MVC 5, @tvanfosson's answer is no longer correct. This may apply to earlier versions as well.

`OnActionExecuted` is always called and has access to the thrown exception via `filterContext.Exception`.

## Test case with exception in an action:

```
public class HomeController
    : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        throw new Exception("Index");
    }
}

public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new Foo());
        filters.Add(new Bar());
    }
}

public class Foo
    : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(Foo)}.{nameof(OnActionExecuting)}");
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(Foo)}.{nameof(OnActionExecuted)}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Has exception: {filterContext.Exception != null}");
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}

public class Bar
    : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(Bar)}.{nameof(OnActionExecuting)}");
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(Bar)}.{nameof(OnActionExecuted)}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Has exception: {filterContext.Exception != null}");
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Bar.OnActionExecuting
Foo.OnActionExecuting
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in WebApplication1.dll
Foo.OnActionExecuted
Has exception: True
Bar.OnActionExecuted
Has exception: True
```

## Test case with exception in a filter

```
public class HomeController
    : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
    }
}

public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new Foo());
        filters.Add(new Bar());
    }
}

public class Foo
    : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(Foo)}.{nameof(OnActionExecuting)}");
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(Foo)}.{nameof(OnActionExecuted)}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Has exception: {filterContext.Exception != null}");
        throw new Exception("Foo");
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}

public class Bar
    : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(Bar)}.{nameof(OnActionExecuting)}");
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(Bar)}.{nameof(OnActionExecuted)}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Has exception: {filterContext.Exception != null}");
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Bar.OnActionExecuting
Foo.OnActionExecuting
Foo.OnActionExecuted
Has exception: False
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in WebApplication1.dll
Bar.OnActionExecuted
Has exception: True
```

Comment: Thanks for updating this for MVC 5!

Comment: Well, where did the answer for MVC <5 go?

Comment: I can confirm the same goes for MVC 4.